# Turtlebot Simulator World not coming up properly

Tags: gazebo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All---

I have been new to ROS and Gazebo and have been trying to get the hands on the turtle bot in Gazebo simulator.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 version and ROS--Indigo and I have followed [this](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_gazebo/Tutorials/indigo/Gazebo%20Bringup%20Guide) tutorial to bring up the Turtle bot in the world describe in the the same link. However, I am not able to get the same world; infact I am only getting a blank world. Moroever, I got the following warning

```
jashanvir@jashanvir-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
... logging to /home/jashanvir/.ros/log/68c77ab0-7d9e-11e6-8601-88532e0c5102/roslaunch-jashanvir-Dell-System-XPS-L502X-19685.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://jashanvir-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:39528/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud_radius: 0.24
 * /cmd_vel_mux/yaml_cfg_file: /opt/ros/indigo/s...
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/output_frame_id: /camera_depth_frame
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/range_min: 0.45
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/scan_height: 10
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 30.0
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    bumper2pointcloud (nodelet/nodelet)
    cmd_vel_mux (nodelet/nodelet)
    depthimage_to_laserscan (nodelet/nodelet)
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    laserscan_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    mobile_base_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    spawn_turtlebot_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [19700]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 68c77ab0-7d9e-11e6-8601-88532e0c5102
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [19713]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [19728]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [19740]
process[spawn_turtlebot_model-4]: started with pid [19745]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5]: started with pid [19746]
process[cmd_vel_mux-6]: started with pid [19747]
process[bumper2pointcloud-7]: started with pid [19748]
process[robot_state_publisher-8]: started with pid [19757]
process[laserscan_nodelet_manager-9]: started with pid [19765]
process[depthimage_to_laserscan-10]: started with pid [19775]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.3
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.3
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.1.5
Exception [Master.cc:50] Unable to start server[bind: Address already in use]. There is probably another Gazebo process running.

Exception [Master.cc:50] Unable to start server[bind: Address already in use]. There is probably another Gazebo process running.

[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 19728, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/jashanvir/.ros/log/68c77ab0-7d9e-11e6-8601-88532e0c5102/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/jashanvir/.ros/log/68c77ab0-7d9e-11e6-8601-88532e0c5102/gazebo-2*.log
```

Could any body provide the fix for the same?
One more thing I want to add is that I waited for 15 minutes so that the world come up but it doesn't.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243967/turtlebot-simulator-world-not-coming-up-properly/) by [taggar_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/28016/taggar_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quoting from the error message : "Unable to start server[bind: **Address already in use**]. There is probably another Gazebo process running."

You should kill any gazebo running first, before launching. Do not launch gazebo at all.

Just plainly execute this command

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```

----.

I got the exact error message you got if I run a gazebo first before launching the turtlebot_gazebo. So I think that is the problem (as also stated in the error message)

----.

Alternatively, you can set different address , if you want to run 2 gazebo at the same time.

---

Originally posted by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) with karma: 582 on 2016-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [taggar_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/28016/taggar_ros/) on 2016-09-19**:
Thanks a lot. It really helps.